# Chmod specific directories using Phing FtpDeploy task

Tags: wordpress, ftp, chmod, phing

I've recently setup a Phing build step to deploy a Wordpress website to an external FTP server.
The actual transfer works fine, but I'm trying to figure out a way to set the permissions on the uploads directory to allow users to upload files.

I notice on the FtpDeploy task in Phing that you can specify dirmode, but that seems to set permissions for all directories that are being deployed.

Can anybody tell me if it's possible to set the directory permissions and upload in a single step (task) or would I have to either do 2 FtpDeploy tasks (one for the bulk of the Wordpress site and a second for the uploads directory alone with the required permissions) or perform an ssh chmod after the deploy task.

If I have to do it in 2 stages, are there any benefits of doing a separate deploy with permissions over the ssh method?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the permissions correctly on your local system, and use the [`dirmode="inherit"`](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#FtpDeployTask) attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd misunderstood the inherit setting to mean "same as parent directory"!